# Client Server related problem

Tags: client-server

Is is possible to connect two computers with a lan cable and then run a server on one computer and access it to another computer. For example running xampp on one computer and open its home page using other computer's browser.

If yes then how to do so? what ip address should i use?

PS: computers are isolated i.e. not connected to any other external environment.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem. Assign **192.168.0.1** to first computer and **192.168.0.2** to second. You are done.

Answer (score 0):

Other options include leaving it at dhcp, and using link local addresses http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address

IPv4 will be 169.254.X.X, and IPv6 will use FE80:....

I don't know if the IPv4 address will be stable, so you may need to assign like gor says.  IPv6 should be stable, unless privacy options are enabled.